# To obtain the attribute from the CSV list

Tags: powershell

There is a list of users in CSV:

```
Name
surname name
```

I want to get to their posts. I use this script:

```
$userList = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\names.csv"
foreach ($User in $userList) {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.Name -Properties DisplayName, title |
        select DisplayName, title |
        Export-Csv -Append "C:\Scripts\title.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

But the script does not find users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the users by their Name or DisplayName you will have to go with Filter instead of Identity. The following should work, assuming your actual AD-users Names are in the format of the csv.

```
$userList = import-csv "C:\Scripts\names.csv" 
ForEach($User in $userList){     
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$($user.Name)'" -Properties DisplayName,title |
select DisplayName,title | Export-CSV -Append "C:\Scripts\title.csv" -NoTypeInformation}
```

Comment: It works if the format is like this:
name surname, but what if I have: surname name ?

Comment: Messy but, I believe changing your Get-ADUser-line to `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$(($user.Name.Split(' ')[1..0]) -join " ")'" -Properties DisplayName, Title` should do the trick.